# ¿Como se usa el usign(MySqlConnection) C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

Hola quiero saber la forma correcta de implementar el `using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection()`
Se supone que al crear una conexión dentro de este `using` al terminar de ejecutar lo que este dentro del bloque liberara los recursos usados en mi caso desconectarme de mi servidor, mis preguntas son
¿Va dentro de una clase?
¿Como obtengo los datos de mi consulta?
Gracias

Comment: No le tengas miedo a la puntuación... facilita la lectura.

Comment: Que quieres decir con eso @sstan soy nuevo por aqui?

Comment: Nada :), solo que tuve que leer la frase siguiente unas cuantas veces antes de poder ponerle las comas mentalmente y entenderla: *Se supone que al crear una conexión dentro de este using al terminar de ejecutar lo que este dentro del bloque liberara los recursos usados en mi caso desconectarme de mi servidor*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un using tiene como propósito liberar los recursos utilizados en su declaración.

```
using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection())
    //abrir conexion
    cn.Open();
    //lógica de programación  encargada de realizar la consulta.
}
```

Puedes implementarlos de la siguiente manera:

Considera que tienes una *tabla relacional* llamada `Prueba_Usuario`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Considera que tienes la siguiente *Entidad* (Clase donde almacenaras los datos)

```
public class Usuario
{
    public Usuario()
    {    
    }
    public String Nombre { get; set; }

    public String ApellidoPaterno { get; set; }

    public String ApellidoMaterno { get; set; }
}
```

Puedes implementar tu *Using* de la siguiente forma , utilizando un patrón llamado *[Data Accesss Object (DAO)](https://danielggarcia.wordpress.com/2009/05/13/abstraccion-de-datos-i-el-patron-dao/)*.

```
public class DaoUsuario
{
  //Almacenamos temporalmente la cadena de conexión
  private string CadenaConexion;

  public  DaoUsuario(string cadenaConexion)
  {
    this.CadenaConexion = cadenaConexion;
  }
  public IEnumerable<Usuario> ConsultarUsuariosPorNombre(string nombre)
  {
    List<Usuario> ListaUsuarios = new List<Usuario>(); //Creamos una lista para agregar acada usuario que leemos de base de datos
    using (MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection(CadenaConexion)) //configuramos la conexión
    {
      try
      {
        //iniciamos la conexion a la base de datos
        conexion.Open();
        MySqlCommand comando = conexion.CreateCommand();
        //configuramos el comando
        comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text; //Indicamos que el comando será una setencia de texto.
        //Considerando que tenemos unta tabla llamada Prueba_Usuario
        comando.CommandText = string.Format(" SELECT nombre, apellidoPaterno, apellidoMaterno FROM Pueba_Usuario where nombre =@parametroNombre");

        comando.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@parametroNombre",nombre)); //le indicamos que remplace @parametroNombre con el valor de nombre

        MySqlDataReader resultado = comando.ExecuteReader(); //Ejecutamos el comando para decirle que nos triga la información de nombre,apellidoPaterno y apellidoMaterno
        //Leeremos cada renglos de la tabla mientras existan datos en ella
        while (resultado.Read())
        {
          Usuario actual = new Usuario();

          actual.Nombre = (string)resultado["nombre"]; //le indicamos el tipo de datos que debe ser con (string)
          actual.ApellidoPaterno = (string)resultado["apellidoPaterno"];
          actual.ApellidoMaterno = (string)resultado["apellidoMaterno"];
          //agregamos el usuario a a lista de usuarios.
          ListaUsuarios.Add(actual);
        }
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {

      throw;
      }
    }
    return ListaUsuarios;
  }
  public IEnumerable<Usuario> ConsultarUsuarios()
  {
    List<Usuario> ListaUsuarios = new List<Usuario>(); //Creamos una lista para agregar acada usuario que leemos de base de datos
    using (MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection(CadenaConexion)) //configuramos la conexión
    {
      //iniciamos la conexion a la base de datos
      conexion.Open();
      MySqlCommand comando = conexion.CreateCommand();
      //configuramos el comando
      comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text; //Indicamos que el comando será una setencia de texto.
      //Considerando que tenemos unta tabla llamada Prueba_Usuario
      comando.CommandText = string.Format(" SELECT nombre, apellidoPaterno, apellidoMaterno FROM Pueba_Usuario");
      MySqlDataReader resultado = comando.ExecuteReader(); //Ejecutamos el comando para decirle que nos triga la información de nombre,apellidoPaterno y apellidoMaterno
      //Leeremos cada renglos de la tabla mientras existan datos en ella
      while (resultado.Read())
      {
        Usuario actual = new Usuario();

        actual.Nombre = (string)resultado["nombre"] ; //le indicamos el tipo de datos que debe ser con (string)
        actual.ApellidoPaterno = (string)resultado["apellidoPaterno"];
        actual.ApellidoMaterno = (string)resultado["apellidoMaterno"];
        //agregamos el usuario a a lista de usuarios.
        ListaUsuarios.Add(actual);
      }
    }
    return ListaUsuarios;
  }
}
```

... y lo puedes instanciar de la siguiente manera:

```
DaoUsuario dao = new DaoUsuario("CadenaConexion");
IEnumerable<Usuario> usuarios = dao.ConsultarUsuarios()   ;
IEnumerable<Usuario> usuarioPorNombre = dao.ConsultarUsuariosPorNombre("nombrePrueba");
```

Comment: Gracias muy completa tu respuesta

Comment: Por favor considera que el DAO es muy básico  y si bien se puede mejorar para hacerlo genérico,este ejemplo te puede ayudar en tu aprendizaje de este patrón de diseño..  Saludos.

Answer (score 4):

Este es un ejemplo como usarlo:

```
public static void Create(Cliente entity)
{
    using (var cn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ToString()) )
    {
        cn.Open();
        using (var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText =
                "INSERT INTO Clientes(RazonSocial, DocumentoIdentidad, NumeroDocumento, Direccion, Telefono)" +
                " VALUES(?RazonSocial, ?DocumentoIdentidad, ?NumeroDocumento, ?Direccion, ?Telefono)";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?RazonSocial", entity.RazonSocial);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?DocumentoIdentidad", entity.DocumentoIdentidad);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?NumeroDocumento", entity.NumeroDocumento);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Direccion", entity.Direccion);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Telefono", entity.Telefono);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }       
    }
 }
```

Respondiendo a tu pregunta:

Al encerrar la declaración del objeto `Connection` entre un bloque `Using` ... `End Using`, nos estaremos asegurando de cerrar la conexión y de destruir los recursos utilizados por el objeto, al finalizar dicho bloque (cuando se ejecute `End Using`). Con ésto no tenemos que estar pendientes de llamar al método `Close` (para cerrar la conexión), ni tampoco al método `Dispose` (para destruir el objeto), por tanto, no es necesario disponer de un procedimiento externo para tales menesteres.

***¿Si va dentro de una clase?*** Si lo puedes poner dentro de una clase para no tener mezclado el código. Es recomendable trabajar en capas: Presenación, Lógica, Persistencia, Entidades. Cada capa tiene una responsabilidad.

- **Presentación:** Se encarga de interactuar con el usuario
- **Lógica:** Se encarga de llamado a métodos y la lógica del negocio
- **Persistencia:** Persistir contra la base de datos
- **Entidades:** Mapeo a datos

Cada capa tiene una responsabilidad y no pueden estar contaminadas con responsabilidades de otras capas.

Answer (score 1):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, todo bloque de código deberá ser ejecutado dentro de una clase.

En este caso, al utilizar `using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection()` no tendrás que cerrar conexiones manualmente ya que la clase `MySqlConnection` hereda de IDisposable, lo cual al finalizar el bloque del `using` la conexión se cierra en automático.

En otras palabras `using` sirve para especificar que un bloque de código será ejecutado y una serie de recursos será asociada al contexto específicado, justo como lo podrían ser conexiones a base de datos. Es una de las mejores prácticas utilizar el contexto `using` debido a que si el tipo que se utiliza en el contexto hereda de la interfaz IDisposable, el objeto se libera de memoria al finalizar el bloque de código del `using` sin tener que disponer de los recursos manualmente.

Este es un código de ejemplo para que puedas manejar los resultados:

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Columna1, Columna2 FROM [Table]";
        conn.Open();
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                try
                {
                    //Manejo de los resultados
                    //string variable1 = reaader["Columna1"].ToString();
                    //string variable2 = reaader["Columna2"].ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    //Manejo de la excepción
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```